# CSS for auto-stacking photo galleries

Tags: css, photo-gallery

I am hoping this is the correct SE forum for this question. I'd like to know what CSS can be used to stack photographs (bunch of `img` tags) so that they're auto-adjusted in width and height on every device screen size. An example is here: www.edwardkb.com/places/ but it's a SquareSpace template so I don't what script or CSS they use. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you use bootstrap 3 , just add img-responsive class in your img tag

```
<img class="img-responsive"  src="...">
```

if you use bootstrap 4, add img-fluid class in your img tag

```
<img class="img-fluid"  src="...">
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. We don't use Bootstrap. Is there a Zurb or Skeleton option for it?